# Jquery draggable not working with containment

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, draggable, containment

My application contains all div's with absolute css position property. Since draggable takes relative position, i need to override it with margin-left and calculate left value for dragged div. It works fine if containment is not specified,

http://jsfiddle.net/W42A4/

```
<div id="main"><div id="draggable">Drag me</div></div>
```

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable({
    axis:"x",
    containment: "#main",
    stop: function( e, ui ) {
        var el = $(this);
        var newLeft = $(el).css("left");
        var newmarginLeft = $(el).css("marginLeft");
        var totalmarginShift = parseFloat(newLeft) + parseFloat(newmarginLeft);
        el
            .css("marginLeft", totalmarginShift)
            .css("left", "")
            .css("top", "")
            .css("position", "absolute");       
    }
});
```

I need containment to restrict draggable div movement out of box, but draggable left does not work.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2TpPS/

I can't find what the problem is. Can anyone suggest me a solution?

Comment: Why do you need to re-set the `left` and `margin`? If the element has been dragged, why would you need to move it again on drop?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Im creating app similar to gantt chart.. Each segment are positon absolute and based on their margin-left values date calculations are performed..On draggable, the segment's position becomes relative and it appends left property rather than margin-left, thereby calculations does not work perfect.. Is there a way for this scenario what i have done in fiddle ?

Answer (score 3):

Just take out all of the unecessary resetting of margins you are doing. Have your jQuery simply:

```
$("#draggable").draggable({
    axis: "x",
    containment: "#main"
});
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/2TpPS/3/

If you want the box to be able to be dragged in any direction remove the `axis: "x"`.

Comment: Yep this works when i tried too.. can u refer my post comment above that explains the scenario..